# Full screen background for start of page

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to make a website that has a full screen background for the start of the webpage but no background for the rest. There is a link of an example below.

Thank You.

EXAMPLE: http://band-theme.tumblr.com/

Comment: And what did you try? What is your question about?

Comment: don't provide any link..better you add a screen shot....

Comment: @AlexPrinceton ... He didn't try anything...Expecting SO will do for him...

Comment: You should give some code of what you have tried etc. We will not code it for you. I can tell you one way to do this tho. Create a div, set its height and width `100%` and put an `background-image` in. Done. What I just said is pretty simple.

Comment: Stackoverflow is  not coding for you. It just helping to solve your problem. But you doesnt have a problem because you even didnt try anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/P59L9/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="home">... Home Content ...</div>
<div id="content">... Website Content ...</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body, #home {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#home {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-1278-873-9.jpg);
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: So exactly what I said in the comments. Its not very hard to do this and I even told them how. You shouldn't give questions like this answers, you just make it look like we will code for any crappy question such as this one.

Comment: @Ruddy true, I might be in a nice but dumb phase this morning :S

Comment: I know its easy rep but try not to do this. People like this should learn to use this site and from this answer I doubt they have learnt anything. Just copied and pasted your code. Cya around the site!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  with the height and with of the page, and give that div a background.

In CSS:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#div_id {
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url("image.png");
}
```

That should work.